# Django multi tenant with SSO dynamically change settings variable CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,TENANT_ID

Tags: django, django-filter, django-settings, django-tenants

How can i change these hardcoded ID's `CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,TENANT_ID` in settings.py depending upon the tenants logged in users

I had implemented django SSO using [django_auth_adfs](https://django-auth-adfs.readthedocs.io/). How can i change these ID's value dynamically based on individual users of each tenant logged in

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package [django-extra-settings](https://pypi.org/project/django-extra-settings/), it will allow you to separate settings per tenant.

i suggest adding a signal to `Client` model, that sets those settings after client `schema/database` is created (make sure you are changing the correct `schema/database`).